# Aligning verbatim text output to text input in fluidrow - R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shinyjs

I am trying to display some input field alongside some output field inputted from another tab. However the output field is going below and cannot align with the rest.

Code given below:-

```
fluidRow(
  column(3, sliderInput(inputId = "avg_planned_miles", label = "Average Planner Miles", min = 5, max = 50, value = 9, step = 0.1)),
  column(3, textInput(inputId = "batch_pct", label = "Batch %", value = "0.5")),
  column(3, h4("Volume: "), verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "planner_volume"))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing the h4() from the last column, or applied it to the first two?  With it you are changing the font size of the third column header which is likely throwing off the alignment.

Comment: h4 is the only way its coming bit closer, otherwise its way down, especially if i use any tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, it looks better to me

```
fluidRow(
  column(3,
         tagList(
           tags$style(type = 'text/css','#avg_planned_miles .irs-grid-text {font-size: 12px}'), #the grid numbers size
           div(id = 'avg_planned_miles', style='font-size: 16px;', #label font size
               sliderInput(inputId = "avg_planned_miles", label = "Average Planner Miles\n", min = 5, max = 50, value = 9, step = 0.1)
           )#div
         )#tags
  ),
  column(3,
         tagList(
           div(id = 'batch_pct',
               style='position:absolute; top:10px; right:5px;', #add margin space 
               textInput(inputId = "batch_pct", width = 280,
                         label = "Batch%", value = "0.5")
           )
         )
  ),
  column(3, p(strong("Volume")), #bold font to match the other fields
         verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "planner_volume", placeholder = 1)
  ),
)
```

You can keep the sliderInput as it is in your code, I thought if the font sizes are bigger it looks better.